# How to count all TDs from a certain column that contain a search term in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, find, contains

I have a page with an HTML table through which I want to loop using JavaScript.

The table has a unique ID ("`trans_log_table`"), no thead but a tbody and I am only interested in the second column of the table. Here I want to count how many TDs contain a certain search term. My search term is a variable called "`orderNum`".

I tried the following but this always returns 0 or nothing. What am I doing wrong here? My guess is I am doing something wrong with the selector, esp. regarding the tr part as want to count all TRs together. For the example below, the result should be 1.

**The HTML (simplified):**

```
<table id="trans_log_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>text1</td><td>text2</td><td>text3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>text1</td><td>text orderNum text</td><td>text3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>text1</td><td>text2</td><td>text3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**My JS:**

```
var orderNum = 'someSearchTerm';
$(objIE.document).find( $('#trans_log_table tr').find("td:eq(1):contains('" + orderNum + "')") ).length
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
$('#trans_log_table tr').find('td:eq(1):contains(' + orderNum + ')').length
```

Unless `objIE` is defined elsewhere, it shouldn't be needed.

Fiddle:  **http://jsfiddle.net/248ddew4/4/**

Comment: Thanks for this ! orderNum is a variable so I think I would need the original as otherwise this is considered as text, no ? This was probably just my bad demo example.

Comment: I wondered about that.  Since `orderNum` is a variable, it should be outside the quotes, and simply removing `objIE` should fix it.  You were very close!

Comment: Thanks. Yes. removing objIE works here but I still think orderNum should be like the original as I am not looking for the term "orderNum" but for the variable "orderNum" which can be any text. Am I wrong here ? Just updated my post for this.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  You can also get rid of `document` altogether.  I'll update my solution.